# Why does enable_shared_from_this have a non-virtual destructor?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, c++11, shared-ptr

I have a pet project with which I experiment with new features of C++11. While I have experience with C, I'm fairly new to C++. To train myself into best practices, (besides reading a lot), I have enabled some strict compiler parameters (using GCC 4.4.1):

```
-std=c++0x -Werror -Wall -Winline -Weffc++ -pedantic-errors
```

This has worked fine for me. Until now, I have been able to resolve all obstacles. However, I have a need for `enable_shared_from_this`, and this is causing me problems. I get the following warning (error, in my case) when compiling my code (probably triggered by `-Weffc++`):

```
base class ‘class std::enable_shared_from_this<Package>’ has a non-virtual destructor
```

So basically, I'm a bit bugged by this implementation of `enable_shared_from_this`, because:

- A destructor of a class that is *intended* for subclassing *should always* be virtual, IMHO.
- The destructor is empty, why have it at all?
- I can't imagine anyone would want to delete their instance by reference to `enable_shared_from_this`.

But I'm looking for ways to deal with this, so my question is really, is there a proper way to deal with this? And: am I correct in thinking that this destructor is bogus, or is there a real purpose to it?

Comment: Have you tried private or protected inheritance? Does it change the diagnostic?

Comment: That's a great idea. But unfortunately, it doesn't.

Comment: `-Weffc++` triggers a lot of pointless (as pertaining to the library) warnings from the standard library, and this is mentioned [in the FAQ](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.wefcxx_verbose)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> A destructor of a class that is intended for subclassing should always be virtual, IMHO.

A virtual destructor in a base class is only needed if an instance of the derived class is going to be deleted via a pointer to the base class.

Having any virtual function in a class, including a destructor, requires overhead.  Boost (and the TR1 and C++11 Standard Library) doesn't want to force you to have that overhead just because you need to be able to obtain a `shared_ptr` from the `this` pointer.

> The destructor is empty, why have it at all?

If you don't have a user-defined constructor, the compiler provides one for you, so it doesn't really matter.

> I can't imagine anyone would want to delete their instance by reference to `enable_shared_from_this`.

Exactly.

As for the compiler warning, I would ignore the warning or suppress it (with a comment in the code explaining why you are doing so).  Occasionally, especially at "pedantic" warning levels, compiler warnings are unhelpful, and I'd say this is one of those cases.

Comment: Unfortunately, with g++ we have to turn off that warning for the entire class... This means you won't get other potential problems (including potential bugs like an uninitialized variable member.)

Answer (score 9):

I agree with Jame's description, but would add

A virtual destructor is only required if you want to destroy an instance of that class virtually.  This is not always the case, however if a base class is not intended to be destroyed virtually it should protect against it

So I would change

> A destructor of a class that is
>   intended for subclassing should always
>   be virtual, IMHO.

this to be:

> A destructor of a class that is
>   intended for subclassing should
>   always be **virtual** or **protected**.

Comment: Hmm.. good point. The destructor of `enable_shared_from_this` actually is protected. So perhaps this is a bug in GCC's `-Weffc++`?

Comment: @Shtééf: Effective C++ says that polymorphic bases should have virtual dtors, and classes not intended for polymorphism should not have virtual dtors. Since the compiler can't tell which is which, I'd say that yes it is a bug to offer this warning. So either your implementation of  IIRC the advice about protected dtors in non-polymorphic base classes if from GotW / Exceptional C++, not Effective.

Comment: Further, my version of the gcc man page says that the `-Wnon-virtual-dtor` warning is only for classes with a virtual function. So either `enable_shared_from_this` has a virtual function (my implementation doesn't), or else the warning isn't following the documentation (which would be a bug), or else the docs have changed (check yours, maybe they explain the warning further). Actually, it's possible that *Effective C++* has been updated - the gcc man page quotes titles which don't match my 3rd edition. So arguably it's a bug in Scott Meyers' book ;-)

Comment: `enable_shared_from_this` doesn't have virtual functions, but GCC will warn if the derived class has virtual functions not only if the base class does.  `-Weffc++` has lots of known flaws, including the fact the Item numbers refer to old editions of the books, some of those Items were removed or rewritten for later editions and the warning hasn't been updated, and in some cases it warns about _style_ not correctness, it's not always useful.  The `-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor` option (which originated with Clang and I added to G++) is more useful than `-Wnon-virtual-dtor`

Answer (score 4):

> *is there a proper way to deal with this?*

Don't use `-Weffc++` all the time.  It's useful to turn it on sometimes to check your code, but not really to use it permanently. It gives false positives and is not really maintained these days.  Use it now and then, but be aware you might have to ignore some warnings.  Ideally, just memorise all the advice in the Meyers books and then you don't need it anyway ;-)

> *am I correct in thinking that this destructor is bogus, or is there a real purpose to it?*

No, it's not bogus and has a real purpose.  **If it wasn't defined it would be implicity-declared as `public`, to prevent that it is explicitly declared as `protected`.**