# std::enable_shared_from_this, non-virtual destructor and public inheritance

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, libstdc++, virtual-destructor, enable-shared-from-this

The [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) class is a (template) mixin, recommended for use to enable creating shared pointers from a given object (or its address), which all have common ownership of the object.

The thing is, that if you have an class T which:

1. Has virtual methods
2. inherits from `std::enable_shared_from_this<T>` (and the inheritance must be public as detailed at the link above; otherwise the mixin is useless)
3. Gets compiled with GCC with `-Wnon-virtual-dtor` (perhaps also with clang, I'm not sure)

you get warnings about the non-virtual destructor of `std::enable_shared_from_this`.

My question is - where is the fault here? That is...

- Should `std::enable_shared_from_this` have a virtual destructor? (I don't think so)
- Should the non-virtual-destructor warning employ some criterion for when it is emitted (if at all enabled, that is)?
- Should the destructor of `std::enable_shared_from_this` be made protected? (And will this even work?)
- Should classes with this mixin not have virtual methods at all?

I'm confused.

Comment: Posible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571850/why-does-enable-shared-from-this-have-a-non-virtual-destructor ?

Comment: @MarshallClow: It's definitely related, but the discussion there does not consider two of the possible alternatives I mentioned. I'm particularly interested in the "protected dtor" alternative not mentioned there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fault; your code is fine. It's merely a false-positive. The point of a warning is to detect pieces of code which, although valid C++, usually indicate problems. But "usually" does not mean "always", so most warnings have cases of false-positives, where it thinks there is misuse when there actually is not.

> Should `std::enable_shared_from_this` have a virtual destructor?

No code is expected to delete a pointer to `enable_shared_from_this`. So no.

> Should the non-virtual-destructor warning employ some criterion for when it is emitted (if at all enabled, that is)?

It's not reasonable for a compiler to know everything about what you're intending to do. It's just seeing something that's usually a problem, which you've decided to have it flag. In this case, it's not a problem.

> Should the destructor of `std::enable_shared_from_this` be made protected?

No.

> Should classes with this mixin not have virtual methods at all?

No.

Comment: If no code is expected to delete an `enable_shared_from_this` - why should that class have a public destructor then?

Comment: Also, edited to reflect my clarifying edit of the question.